# Ember eror Attempted to register a view with an id already in use

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Has anyone noticed an error in Ember app with the following message;

"Assertion Failed: Attempted to register a view with an id already in use: MyGridId"

Any idea of where I should be looking for ?

Comment: Welcome to [so] please add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help people answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this properly you tried to assign a `MyGridId` variable as an `id`.

I'd say look for `id="MyGridId"` and replace with `id={{MyGridId}}` in a template.

Comment: yes MyGridId is the id value given by me...But it is not part of the template code. It is in my JS code